# Can questions that have been poorly recieved be rewritten to a new question?

Tags: discussion

This question was poorly received but the edit ultimately changes the question. I am still having trouble finding the right words to express my imagination and sometimes a comment bring it into perspective for me. Since it has no answers can I delete it and rewrite it with the correct wording?

[A lander/SSTO and a "transport stage" that remains in orbit](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/34908/a-lander-ssto-and-a-transport-stage-that-remains-in-orbit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as "can I delete it", of course you can.

Also, since the new question is so different than the old question, posting it would be like posting any new question.

My personal recommendation however, in this particular case would be to let the process of reopening continue as its already underway. I like this because it works within the SE system using the tools and procedures in the correct way by responding to comments and close votes and improving the question.

Whenever there are options like this, going along with a standard SE procedure is usually the best way to go. These have evolved over about a decade and millions of posts and are probably better than "creative problem solving" options.

Comment: OP should also note that a strategy of deleting and reasking used repeatedly could trigger a question ban.

Comment: @called2voyage I refrained. thanks